# Using a constant in require_once

Tags: php, require-once

I'm using the following to define root while in development:

```
define('LOCAL_URL', 'http://localhost/~xampp/Mysite');
define('REMOTE_URL', 'http://example.com');
define('DEV_VERSION', true);
if(DEV_VERSION)
    define('URL', LOCAL_URL);
else
    define('URL', REMOTE_URL);
```

This concept is new to me and I'm a bit of a PHP beginner so please be gentle.

I'm trying to use 'URL' in 'require_once' and I can't seem to get it to work (as in the required file is not included). I've tried the following:

```
require_once URL.'/phpincludes/coming-events.php';
require_once(URL.'/phpincludes/coming-events.php');
require_once URL . '/phpincludes/coming-events.php';
require_once (URL . '/phpincludes/coming-events.php');
require_once(URL.'phpincludes/coming-events.php');
```

I've checked http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php and have searched on Stackoverflow and I'm not really making any headway at all.

I'm sure it's a really stupid and basic error I'm making here, but I'm at a loss and would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Looks like you got bad advise with your last question. Use the different base URLs only for outputting HTML references. (Regarding that stylesheet issue, just use it in `<base href=...>` to compensate).

Comment: Thanks mario. So I shouldn't even be using it for img paths? ie. `<img src="<?php echo URL ?>/images/something.jpg">`

Comment: A single base href will make images and stylesheets work. But only if you have relative paths. Otherwise you need the URL prefix everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably because `URL` has a protocol, and it is trying to open the file over HTTP.

Including files remotely is disabled by default in PHP ([`allow_url_include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)), and for good reason.

You should be passing relative or absolute paths to files in your filesystem to be included.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm using `define` so I can use relative paths, so now I'm really confused. I posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975313/using-root-relative-urls-and-problems-with-testing-locally) yesterday which resulted in my using `define`. I don't fully understand what you're saying but I'll... uhm... try something else perhaps?